# How can I extern classes in a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I want to extern classes in a namespace, without defining the entire class again. For example, I have class `A`:

```
class A
{
    private:
        int value;
    public:
        A(int value);
        int get_value();
};
```

and class `B`:

```
class B
{
    private:
        int value;
    public:
        B(int value);
        int get_value();
};
```

But I want to extern the `A` and `B` classes, without defining all of them in the namespace again, like:

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"

namespace kc
{
    extern class A;
    extern class B;
}
```

and I don't want to do:

```
namespace kc
{
    class A
    {
        private:
            int value;
        public:
            A(int value);
            int get_value();
    };
    class B
    {
        private:
            int value;
        public:
            B(int value);
            int get_value();
    };
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by extern classes in a namespace? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If the class is supposed to be in the namespace `kc`, why do you define it outside of it as well? Are you aware that you can just write `namespace kc { class A /*...*/ }` in the other header files as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refer to the same classes as though they were members of the namespace, then you can do that with a pair of using declarations.

```
namespace kc
{
    using ::A;
    using ::B;
};
```

Note however, that this *does not* make the classes into members of the namespace, and language features like ADL won't be affected by it.