# How can I extern namespaces in a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71124571/how-can-i-extern-classes-in-a-namespace), I asked that how can I extern classes in a class, and we could do:

```
namespace kc
{
    using ::A;
    using ::B;
}
```

instead of:

```
namespace kc
{
    class A
    {
        private:
            int value;
        public:
            A(int value);
            int get_value();
    };
    class B
    {
        private:
            int value;
        public:
            B(int value);
            int get_value();
    };
}
```

And now, I want to do something like this for namespaces, without defining the entire namespace again. I tried to use the same code, but it doesn't work: `error: using-declaration may not name namespace <namespace_name>`

**Edit**

Actually, I'm making a kernel, and that's my code (`pio.hpp`):

```
#pragma once

namespace pio
{
    void outb(unsigned short port, unsigned char value);
    void outw(unsigned short port, unsigned short value);
    unsigned char inb(unsigned short port);
    unsigned short inw(unsigned short port);
}
```

And (`k.hpp`):

```
#pragma once

#include <pio.hpp>
#include <cursor.hpp>

namespace k
{
    using ::pio;
    using ::cursor;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do with namespaces.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't understand what's unclear. You want to know, why I'm doing this? Or what?

Comment: @NoIdeaForUsername It isn’t clear because `extern namespace` isn’t a thing in C++ (but `extern class` probably also doesn’t do what you think it does).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I know, there's no `extern namespace` in C++. Actually, I used the "extern" word, to say what I want (I had no idea about the word). I also gave an example of what I want. The only difference in this question and the previous question is using classes in a namespace, and namespaces in a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you’re looking for is a [namespace alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias):

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        struct C {};
    }
}

namespace X {
    namespace Y = ::A::B;
}
```

This would allow you to write e.g.

```
X::Y::C foo;
```

Comment: I edited my question